# perl: Text::Fuzzy, different string giving same edit distance?

Tags: perl, edit

Checking distance between `$barcode` and two strings, first string has same 12 characters at the front and another is completely different but both gives same distance?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Text::Fuzzy;
my $barcode =  "TCCCTTGTCTCC";

foreach my $line1 (<DATA>) {
    print "New string\n";
    print "Barcode length:", length $barcode, "\nSequence length:",
    length $line1, "\n";
    my $tf = Text::Fuzzy->new($barcode);
    my $ed = $tf->distance($line1);
    print "Edit distance: ", $ed ,"\n\n";
}

__DATA__
TCCCTTGTCTCCCCTGATATCCTGTAAAATCCTTTTCTTCTGATGGGTGCCATTTGCCACTAGAGGAAGCTGAACAGACCTGACTACCTGGA
GACGAGACTGATCACCTGATATCCTGTAAAATCCTTTTCTTCTGATGGGTGCCATTTGCCACTAGAGGAAGCTGCAGACCTGACTACCTGGA
```

Outputs:

```
New string
Barcode length:12
Sequence length:93
Edit distance: 81

New string
Barcode length:12
Sequence length:93
Edit distance: 81
```

Answer (score 2):

That seems right since all the characters of subsequence are present in the longer sequence both would have the same Levenshtein  edit distance. This is so because all it would need is deletions to transform the  longer to shorter sequence

Example :

`artic => arc` edit distance 2, i.e deletions 2 
`arche => arc` would have the same edit distance 2 i.e deletions 2

Comment: Is there anyway to get difference in such case, with substitutions too?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is [longest common substring](http://search.cpan.org/~dyacob/String-LCSS-0.12/lib/String/LCSS.pm)

Answer (score 2):

Sure. In the first case, all of the characters in `$barcode` appear together at the beginning of the line, so it takes 81 (93 - 12) edits to add all of the other characters at the end.

In the second case, all of the characters in `$barcode` still appear, in order, just with a bunch of stuff in between. Since they do, no deletions or substitutions are necessary, and the distance is still 81, the characters are just added in different places. To illustrate:

```
GACGAGACTGATCACCTGATATCCTGTAAAATCCTTTTCTTC ...
________T___C_CCT_______TGT______CT___C__C ...
```